# Is HaikuOS stable enough for everyday use yet?

Tags: haiku

I was always a fan of BeOS and I have been watching [HaikuOS](http://haiku-os.org/) for a while now. I would like to try it out, but if there is still problems with wireless drivers/configuration etc. then it would still be too immature for me.

Can it be used as a main OS for everyday web browsing etc yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really ready for use as a primary OS by the general public although it's already quite stable so if you're feeling adventurous and are knowledgeable about the environment you could. They still haven't announced a firm date for R1 but rumor has it it's fast approaching.

You've probably seen this but in case you haven't here's [what they say](http://www.haiku-os.org/about/faq#6):

> We do not have a firm release date [for R1] . Haiku development is advancing steadily, and when a stage is reached where the development team feels confident about setting a target release date, an official announcement to that effect will be made

Answer (score 0):

It's probably stable enough for a personal machine. I'd still take the usual precaution of backing up critical data.